# Finding which js file to edit from firebug

Tags: javascript, firebug

I am using firebug to edit my magento theme. In a particular element I am getting an element.style attribute that I want to edit. Now how do I know which JS file is to be edited?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to interact with elements via Javascript, you can use the console function in Firebug. Go to console, and click enable and from there you can start typing code as if it were javascript.

Example, if you wanted to check the z-index property of a specific element you could just type the javascript in the console:

```
document.getElementById("idOfElement").style.z-index
```

and when you hit enter it should tell you. You can also see errors in the javascript file if there are any.

If you are looking for the Javascript file of what is committing this change in the z-index property and you are 100% certain it is because of the Javascript, then you can use the debugger Firebug has which is also in the Scripts tab. If you're dealing with multiple javascript files, I'm not entirely sure how you can sift through which JS file is causing it, I believe you'll have to do that digging on your own. The debugger allows you step through your JS file though and see what changes are being made step-by-step.

Here is a [tutorial](http://thecodecentral.com/2007/08/01/debug-javascript-with-firebug#header-2) on how to use the debugger if you're not familiar. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about firebug,

But if you use linux you may try this command,

> grep "element.style" -Rn .

Answer (score 0):

Do you Want to change the Style or Something other. 
If you want to change Style of a Particular Element, Just Follow the Steps

1. F12
2. Select Inspect Tool
3. Click on the Element where you want to change
4. In a FireBug Window look at Right and Make Sure style Tab is Selected
5. Just Single Click on value of a Particular Property

If you are not finding solution, Please Determine the Problem bit Clearly.

Comment: I already know what element to be edited and also familiar with using firebug, Its just that the property i.e. z-index is coming from a javascript file and not from a css file. Hence the property is under the element.style field for that element. Now I want to know whats the Javscript file that is doing this z-index thing.